# PowerShell Producing Unreadable Output

Tags: powershell

[Image Here For Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekAVz.png)
Specifically the text after "Similarity" and "->"

I have a small PowerShell script that uses ssh to connect to a server and run a command.
I believe it produces unreadable output due to some of the text having to be in colour.

I've tried adding the following, but still no luck:

```
$OutputEncoding = [console]::InputEncoding = [console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding
```

Comment: I suspect that you passing output commands (that usually should be at the end of the pipeline) to another cmdlet. In other words, what are you trying to do? What commands do you give? Please, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72908898/1701026) your question and add a [mcve] to it.

Comment: Start your SSH in monochrome by setting the environment variable TERM=xterm-mono

Comment: @iRon I was tagging music with the beets python module, can be found here: https://beets.io/
The command I ran was "beet import"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, turns out that the command I needed was `ssh -t host command` to enable the colour display

More info here: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ssh+-t+my_host+my_command

Answer (score 0):

To define console encoding you can use following expressions.

Choose encoding you need.

```
$ConsoleEncoding =  [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
```

Apply your encoding to console.

```
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding( "$( $ConsoleEncoding.BodyName )" )
```